# Associativity of Element-Wise Matrix Multiplication and Division?

Tags: matrices

In general, does the order of evaluation matter?

$Y \odot W \oslash X$

The above operators are element-wise multiplication and division, respectively. $Y$, $W$, and $X$ are $n\times m$ matrices.

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the matrices are over a skew field and assuming that no entry of $X$ is zero, we can take the multiplicative inverse of each element of $X$ to get a new matrix $Z$. Then the element-wise associativity of $Y\odot W\oslash X = Y\odot W\odot Z$ follows from associativity of multiplication in a ring.